# I see many examples of C++ with the use of "Foo ^ bar" - what is "^"?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Is that .NET related?
It appears to be a pointer of some sort, what is the difference?

Edit:

I actually know it is the XOR operator, but look at this example from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms379600(v=vs.80)).

```
void objectCollection() {
    using namespace System::Collections;

    ArrayList ^as = gcnew ArrayList;

    //... 
}
```

What is this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're looking at constructs of the form:

```
Foo ^bar = gcnew Foo();
```

You're right, in .NET it is a pointer-"like" type and is part of C++/CLI, not but not standard ISO C++.

It's a reference to a garbage-collected, managed .NET object as opposed to a regular, unmanaged C++ object.

As the other poster suggest, outside the .NET world or in a non-object creation context, it is the XOR operator.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, that is the [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor) operator.

Comment: +1 to nullify the -1 because the answer was given before the question was edited to include the example.

Answer (score 0):

That's a handle to a .NET reference type, when using Managed C++. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

Comment: That's C++/CLI - Managed C++ is another beast that was mercifully put down.